# Need conditional formatting on cells that already have a subtraction formula

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a column (let's say column X) that subtracts dates in 2 other different columns (let's say S and T) to tell me by color of cell fill if something was delivered on time or late.
In addition, I would like to add conditional formatting to the same column x in a new color that indicates if the delivery was made at all and is past the due date.
First question - Am I able to add conditional formatting to column x since there's already a formula in the column.
Second question - what is the formula for this?

Tried a number of things..

Thanks so much!

Comment: (1) Yes, a cell can contain a formula and independently have conditional formatting.   (2) I’m too lazy to bother to understand your data.   Write a formula that determines whether the delivery was made at all and is past the due date, and you’re done.

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXKWf.png) basically what you want?

Comment: Or is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1eC8.png) closer to what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

With conditional formatting you can combine only formats that don't rule each other out. For example you can have one format that makes the cell fill red when condition X is true, and another conditional format that makes the text bold if condition Y is true. If set up correctly, the cell will show red fill and bold text independently, so that when both X and Y are true, it will show bold text on red fill.

If, however, your second conditional formatting rule also changes the cell fill, you will need to determine with rule "wins" when both X and Y are true. This is achieved by changing the order of the rules or with the "Stop if true" setting in the Conditional Formatting Manager dialog.

You can, however, set up the second conditional format in a neighboring column, so that you have several fill color flags side by side in different columns.

[image]